# I downloaded shapefile but merging with internal dataset based on geometry fails

Tags: r, gis, tmap

Apologies as i'm a little new to GIS features within R, so any help and explanation would be very helpful!

I have downloaded this shape file (Simple Feature Polygon) from source like so:

```
fire <-tempfile()
download.file("http://frap.fire.ca.gov/webdata/data/statewide/fhszs.sn.zip",destfile = fire)
unzip(fire,exdir = ".")
fire_map<-read_shape("fhszs06_3.shp")
```

Map has small polygons based on Hazard code (i.e.: 1,2,3)

I also have an internal dataframe that is about 15 variables with 3584 rows, I also have lat/lon for all points (commercial properties in california) that I'm trying to convert to either spatial points DF or simple feature in order to figure out which properties lie within a  hazard code.

Example of property file:

```
ln_bal<- c(500000,200000,6000000,12000,130000)
ln_city <-c('Ventura','Torrance','Buena Park','Concord','Lake View Terrace')
lon <- c(-119.213504,-118.311072,-117.985452,-122.057139,-116.893845)
lat <-c(34.278122,33.844817,33.846594,37.979995,32.844287)

cmbs3 <- data.frame(ln_bal,ln_city,lon,lat)
```

I think my problem is getting the correct CRS and then matching with the shape file. 
The CA Fire map has the following:

```
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    +proj=aea +lat_1=34 +lat_2=40.5 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-120 +x_0=0 +y_0=-4000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

I've Tried sf_intersect by creating a SF points DF:

```
fire_map <-st_read("fhszs06_3.shp")%>%
 st_transform(4326)  #need to set CRS the same as your dataframe below

#transforms coordinates to ellips code and creates matching values with fire_map: 

proj4string(cmbs3)<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
cmbs3 <- spTransform(cmbs3, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=51 ellps=WGS84"))

#fire_map is a simple feature data frame need to convert our data to this, and then match
cmbs3<-st_as_sf(cmbs3,precision=0)
cmbs3<-st_set_crs(cmbs3,4326)

inters <- st_intersection(cmbs3,fire_map)
```

Expected (potential) Results:

```
ln_bal     ln_city    lon           lat    HAZ_CODE   HAZ_CLASS
12000       Concord   -122.057139   37.97     1           Moderate
```

Comment: That zipped shapefile does not seem to be downloading for me - no connection to the server.

Comment: I found the map from the website here the "State Responsibility Area:   http://www.fire.ca.gov/fire_prevention/fire_prevention_wildland_statewide

Comment: I wonder if that's blocked for non-US access? I can't get it but https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/fire.ca.gov says its up. Ho hum.